# GitHub push Error occurs. (ssh key doesn't work)

Tags: git, github, github-pages

**Problem Description**:
While I try to push to GitHub Pages I got an Error .

```
ERROR: Permission to lut/EvolutionApp.git denied to ~.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've searched this for 3 days, and I've tried all solutions but it didn't work at all. I don't know since when but, I've changed branch `master` to `main`(remote and local both).
I'm not sure this is the main problem.
**I've tried**:

1. I generated `ssh key` and add it to GitHub Settings.
   when I write `>ssh -T git@github.com` it shows `Hi DanielFH1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

**Status**:
1.

```
# I've changed default branch master to main
>git status 
on branch main
```

2. 

```
>git remote
origin
```

3. 

```
# I've deleted branch master and leave only default branch 'main'
>git branch -d master
Deleted branch master (was 6eca8640).
```

4. 

```
>git branch
* main
```

**Full Error**:  errors are mainly cannot push(1) or pull(2)
1.

```
>git push origin main
ERROR: Permission to lut/EvolutionApp.git denied to ~.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

2. 

```
>git pull origin main
fatal: couldn't find remote ref main
```

3. 

```
# It seems it connected to port 22 as github description says, and says 'successfully   
 authenticated' in the last line. Are these means OK?
>ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to github.com [52.78.231.108] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-17a926d7
debug1: no match: babeld-17a926d7
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:isIh1SLbiAdxDs2LohVlLlC4mXm0bKEWPhMvuZLlpuQ C:\\Users\\SeungWoo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 407
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([52.78.231.108]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi DanielFH1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2944, received 2912 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
```

Comment: Your ssh keypair belongs to the user "DanielFH1" but you're trying to push to a repo belonging to the user "lut". Do you have permissions to push to user's "lut" repositories?

Comment: I changed remote repo url and set the branch to 'main' in pages setting. and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The local branch is not in sync with remote. Git reset --hard is one option